# Is there a CSS not equals selector?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Is there something like != (not equal) in CSS?
e.g, I have the following code:

```
input {
 ... 
 ...
}
```

but for some inputs I need to void this. I'd like to do that by adding the class "reset" to the input tag, e.g.

```
<input class="reset" ... />
```

and then simply skip this tag from CSS.

How I can do that?

The only way I can see would be to add some class to the input tag, and rewrite the CSS as follows:

```
input.mod {
 ...
 ...
}
```

Comment: You answered your question, I think. Put the style in input.mod and add class 'mod' in the desired input tag.

Answer (score 174, accepted):

In CSS3, you can use the `:not()` filter, <strike>but not all browsers fully support CSS3 yet, so be sure you know what you're doing</strike> which is now 
[supported by all major browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=%3Anot()) (and has been for quite some time; this is an *old* answer...).

Example:

```
<input type="text" value="will be matched" />
<input type="text" value="will not be matched" class="avoidme" />
<input type="text" value="will be matched" />
```

and the CSS

```
input:not(.avoidme) { background-color: green; }
```

---

**Note:** this workaround shouldn't be necessary any more; I'm leaving it here for context.

If you don't want to use CSS3, you can set the style on all elements, and then reset it with a class.

```
input { background-color: green; }
input.avoidme { background-color: white; }
```

Comment: OMG... I knew that it's exist :)
Yeah, it is! Thanks.

Comment: The support is lacking mainly from IE8 (and older releases). If anyone is interested in a polyfill: http://selectivizr.com/

Comment: IS any option for multiple classes in not()?

Comment: @Guru: You can chain multiple `:not()` selectors: `input:not(.avoidme):not(.avoidmetoo)` will avoid elements with either class, `input:not(.avoidme.andme)` will avoid elements with *both* classes.

Comment: @TomasLycken, actually, using multiple selectors is a tricky one in CSS, e.g. `:not(.this.that) {  }` MAY work, but if you do something such as `:not(.this, .that) {  }` you'll fall down, you have to daisy chain them such as: `:not(.this):not(.that)`. I understand you probably know this, I am trying to help future readers :)

Comment: Leaving a comment here for future readers: @SamSwift웃's comment is still accurate, but [support for lists is (maybe) coming in the future](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-not-sel-list). For now, though, only single selectors are supported inside `:not()`.

Answer (score 24):

You can also do that by 'reverting' the changes on the reset class only in CSS.

```
INPUT { 
    padding: 0px;
}
INPUT.reset {
    padding: 4px;
}
```

Answer (score 13):

You could also approach this by targeting an attribute like this:

`input:not([type=checkbox]){
  width:100%;
}`

In this case all inputs that are not 'checkbox' type will have a width of 100%.

Answer (score 9):

CSS3 has `:not()`, but it's not implemented in all browsers yet.  It is implemented in the IE9 Platform Preview, however.

```
input:not(.reset) { }
```

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#negation

In the meantime, you'll have to stick to the old-fashioned methods.

Answer (score 5):

Interesting just tried this for selecting DOM element using JQuery and it works! :)

```
$("input[class!='bad_class']");
```

This page has 168 divs which does not have class 'comment-copy'

```
$("div[class!='comment-copy']").length => 168
$("div[class!='.comment-copy']").length => 168
```

Comment: `[attr!="value"]` is a **jQuery-only** selector http://api.jquery.com/attribute-not-equal-selector/

Comment: What does this have to do with CSS?

Comment: @devlincarnate "CSS" selectors have bled into JS ([circa 2013](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api/#interface-definitions)) so people search for it.

Answer (score 0):

instead of class="reset" you could reverse the logic by having class="valid"
You can add this by default and remove the class to reset the style.

So from your example and Tomas'

```
input.valid {
 ... 
 ...
}
```

and

```
<input type="text" value="will be matched" class="valid"/>
<input type="text" value="will not be matched" />
<input type="text" value="will be matched" class="valid"/>
```

Comment: I think the whole idea of being able to "reset" by applying to a class was that the number of elements that shouldn't have the default style greatly exceeded the ones that should, so the OP didn't want to apply *any* class to the majority of the elements.