# Clicking with javascript by class, takes wrong class as well

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

I am using the following javascript snippet in Chrome's console, for debugging purposes.

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll('a[class="_5glz _53o _53b"]');
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    links[i].click();
    console.log(i);
}
```

The class i need to be clicked is _5glz _**53o** _53b and the class i need to be ignored is _5glz _**53p** _53b

I am trying to make a chrome plugin with various automated tasks for facebook, like the Toolkit for Facebook plugin.

Do you guys know what am i doing wrong here? Thanks.

Sample asked by Mac:

```
<div class="_5gl-" id="u_35_0"><a href="#" role="button" class="_5glz _53o _53b">Like</a><a href="#" role="button" class="_5glz _53p _53b">Unlike</a><span class="_6ib"> · </span><a class="_5glz _s4z" role="button" href="#" id="u_35_1">Comment</a><a class="_5gly _5glz" role="button" aria-label="3 likes" href="#" id="u_35_2"><table class="uiGrid _51mz _53z" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tbody><tr class="_51mx"><td class="_51m- pam _51mw"><table class="uiGrid _51mz" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" aria-label="3 likes"><tbody><tr class="_51mx"><td class="_51m- pas"><div class="_29qi"><i class="img sp_MVADFc4iUN7_1_5x sx_3bfd01"></i></div></td><td class="_51m- pas _51mw"><div class="_50f3">3</div></td></tr></tbody></table></td></tr></tbody></table></a></div>
```

Comment: You are aware that those class names change all the time?

Comment: @WizKid yes, this is not a problem for me, i'll try to keep them updated. The problem is it clicks the wrong ones too :/

Comment: Do you have errors ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a CSS not equals selector?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3353968/is-there-a-css-not-equals-selector)

Comment: @tyteen4a03 it's not, because i need to select the correct class with JScript. I am not writting any css or whatsoever.

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai nope, i don't!

Comment: Try this: `$(links[i]).click()`

Comment: `querySelectorAll()` uses CSS selectors to select elements.

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai the problem is in "querySelectorAll" not the clicking functionality.

Comment: Please try this: `document.querySelectorAll('a._5glz _53o _53b')`

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai didn't work either. It didn't select any "A" tag.

Comment: Please post your html.

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai just use any Facebook profile's photo album!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did it with:

```
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("_53o");
for (i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
    if (elems[i].offsetWidth > 0 && elems[i].offsetHeight > 0) {
        console.log(i);
        elems[i].click();
    }
}
```

Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

So I believe you'll need to use the regex selectors:

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll('a[class~="_5glz"][class~="_53o"][class~="_53b"]');
```

So this will select all  tags whose class attribute contains the **words** "_5glz" *and* "_53o" *and* "_53b"

Alternatively, you can also go with negation:

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll('a[class~="_5glz"][class~="_53b"]:not([class~="_53p"])');
```

Depends what you need to do...

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hey Mac, It still unlikes everything i liked, and vice versa, no matter which way i try!

Comment: Hmmm - ok, which browser are you using? And could you paste a sample html snippet we could test with? Thanks!

Comment: Mac, i updated the question, added a sample. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks - seems to work for me however. I put your html sample in an html document. Then in the browser's console (in this case I used Chrome - but that shouldn't matter) I paste in `document.querySelectorAll('a[class~="_5glz"][class~="_53o"][class~="_53b"]');` and I only get the one anchor, the "Like" anchor node...?

Comment: When trying to do it Live (in an actual Facebook photo album) it picks up the wrong "A" tags too. Tried to do it with the sample i provided, in my XAMPP and worked too. I assume Facebook makes the Like / Unlike link invisible but leaves it there, so when i re-execute the script it does the oposite to already-liked photos.... is it a dead-end? :/

Comment: It might be... I'd unfortunately call what you are trying to do as a "hack", i.e. trying to manipulate someone else's code/DOM without a publicly available API... Even if you did get it to work today, FB could change things tomorrow and totally break your code... I'd instead look into public APIs, or some other way to produce the results you want

Comment: Mac, it's already done with a chrome plugin called Toolkit for Facebook, but it has some issues i'd like to cover with a new plugin of mine. Anyway, do you see any possible solution to the horizon? :/

Comment: Not without a more complete example... Where in the FB UI is this?

Comment: Mac, in any photo album (i use my own for the tests)